# How to add Custom Keystroke event for a combobox using Itextsharp and Javascript?

Tags: itext, acrobat

I have a pdf form , and I dynamically add a combo box to this existing pdf form using Itextsharp.

On the change event of the combo box, I need to update the selected value of combo box to a text field.

This is the script I need to add to the custom keystroke event of the combo box.

```
if (!event.willCommit){this.getField("TR6").value=event.changeEx}
```

Is there any way to add this script via Itextsharp.